# Kubuntu hanging a long time on plymouth when shutting down or rebooting

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown, plymouth

Not much more to say as I can't see anything in any logs I've checked to indicate any errors. I don't run any servers or virtual machines that need shutting down.
It used to shutdown almost instantly but now seems to hang for a couple of minutes on/in plymouth for no apparent reason and I'm at a loss where to check to see what's causing the hang.

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Sounds like something is hitting a timeout. You can detect this by letting it complete a shutdown (take a walk, eat a peach, have a nap). Then reboot and `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` will show it.

Comment: @waltinator There don't appear to be any problems in the output. I keep wondering if this has something to do with my lwm2.I saw something a while back that said if the shutdown hangs, check the lvm2 monitor is running. But when I check with service lvm2-monitor status, it says active (exited) with a zero code. Like just now it says my service exited 29 minutes ago, so that would suggest that the monitor is not running, and so ties in with the article I read saying it would be the cause of a shutdown hang, but if so, I have no idea why it exits.

Comment: @David Kubuntu 20.04